# Check if a list of strings contains letters from another list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, counter

So I have two lists:

```
vocabulary = ['a','b','c']
sentences = ['a a b b c c', 'a c b c', 'b c c a b']
```

I want to calculate how many times the letters in vocabulary appear in the strings in the list sentences.

So I want the output to be:

```
a = 4
b = 5
c = 6
```

My program:

```
counter = Counter()
for word in sentences:
    if word in vocabulary:
        counter.update(word)
print(counter)
```

But I keep getting the output:

```
Counter()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`. [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) accepts another dictionary or an iterable of pairs. But you're only supplying a single character.

In this case, you can chain your list of strings and pass to `Counter`, then filter the result via a dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

vocabulary = ['a','b','c']
sentences = ['a a b b c c', 'a c b c', 'b c c a b']

vocab_set = set(vocabulary)
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(sentences))
res = {k: v for k, v in c.items() if k in vocab_set}

{'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, no `import` needed:

```
vocabulary = ['a','b','c']
sentences = ['a a b b c c', 'a c b c', 'b c c a b']

data = ''.join(sentences)

for v in vocabulary:
    print('{}: {}'.format(v, data.count(v)))

a: 4
b: 5
c: 6
```

Comment: Worth noting this is at the cost of time complexity O(*m* * *n*) vs O(*n*).

Answer (score 1):

An *O(n)* solution, with no `import`:

```
vocabulary = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sentences = ['a a b b c c', 'a c b c', 'b c c a b']

counts = {}
vocab_set = set(vocabulary)
for sentence in sentences:
    for ch in sentence:
        if ch in vocab_set:
            counts[ch] = counts.get(ch, 0) + 1

print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
{'c': 6, 'a': 4, 'b': 5}
```